# Javascript expression evaluation - confusion

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an expression like below

```
console.log('isSuperAdmin ' + user.user_role === "SUPER_ADMIN");
```

which is printing **false** on console. But, clearly the value of `user.user_role` is indeed `"SUPER_ADMIN"` and on **DevTool**, when I hover on the expression `user.user_role === "SUPER_ADMIN"`, I am getting a popup as `true`. Can you please tell me, why the expression is getting evaluated as `false` at the end?

**PS:** I am new to Javascript, so please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Google for "JavaScript operator precedence". Precedence is sort of like, where JS puts the parentheses for you.

Comment: Do you also expect `1 + 2 === 2` to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operation is done before the `===` so the easiest solution is to surround it with `()`, but it could be even better if you add the second statement as another parameter to the `console.log()`, so your debug window can show it in an appropiate way.

```js
console.log("text" + 1 === 1);
console.log("text" + (1 === 1));
console.log("text", 1 === 1);
```